# How to create a product images slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to create a product slider like the one in dicksmith's product page(http://www.dicksmith.com.au/razer-deathadder-ergonomic-gaming-mouse-dsau-yg10178)
[image]

The layout should be similar, the images are read from database. Does anyone have sample source code? Or give me an advice(using jQuery,ajax or CSS are all OK). Thanks

Comment: Sorry I added -1, this issue is very easy to find in google if you search jquery sliders or carousels. The quick (not best) solution I'll give you is to use bootstrap carousel. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel, you can replace bootstrap circle pagination with images.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var $slider = $('.product-img-box').find('.Zoom-Box');
        if( $slider.length > 0 ) {
            $slider.carouFredSel({
                auto                : false,
                circular            : true,
                responsive          : true,
                scroll: {
                    fx : "crossfade",
                    easing : "linear",
                    // pauseOnHover    : true,
                    duration        : 1000,
                },
                swipe: {
                    onMouse         : true,
                    onTouch         : true
                },
                next: {
                    button          : '.right-nav',
                    key             : 'right'
                },
                prev: {
                    button          : '.left-nav',
                    key             : 'left'
                },
            }, {
                wrapper: {
                    classname       : 'Zoom-Box-wrapper',
                }
            });
        }
```

Should using plugin for it.. you can download the plugin first.
URL: https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel